# How to properly exit a child process within a thread?

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

I am trying to handle timeouts within threads. My script has 4 threads, each thread needs to execute commands, and kill the command process if it takes too long.

What I am doing is:

```
my $pid;
if (!($pid = fork))
  {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    my $pid2;
    if (!($pid2 = fork))
      {
        exec_cmd $command;
      }
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {kill 9, $pid2;};
    alarm $timeout;
    waitpid $pid2, 0;

    exit(0);
  }
  waitpid $pid, 0;
  $ret = $?;
```

This is executed inside a thread, so when the child exits, other threads are still unjoined.

Comment: This code uses forks, not threads.

Comment: Yes but it is just a part of the script, this piece of code is called inside a thread

Comment: How do I properly exit a child process within a thread?

Comment: While other threads are still running.
The exec_cmd function calls exec so there is no problem. However the first fork needs to exit with the cmd's exit status and if i just do exit Perl says there are still running threads, which is normal, but how can I exit those threads ? I have tried killing them by iterating through threads->list (), and kill('KILL')->detach but it still shows a message later saying there are detached threads

Comment: Threads an forks don't play well together. I don't know how perl implements threads, but it is quite possible that after a fork, the child process ends up with all the threads the parent process had at fork time, so that the lingering threads you see are extra ones created by the fork.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, then how can I timeout commands in threads, since there's only one alarm per process

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you are asking, how can I enforce a time limit on the execution of a child process spawned from a perl thread, and capture that child's exit code?

**The easiest thing you could do** (on a UNIX system) is to set an alarm on the child process itself:

```
my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) and $pid == 0) {
  alarm($timeout);  # Preserved across exec()
  exec(...);
  die "exec(): $!";
}
```

Exit status will still be available in `waitpid`/`$?` as usual.

**The safest thing you could do** is not to fork while multithreading.  It's dangerous both for the application and the implementation.  The application, because the child will have running copies of the parent's threads.  The implementation, because it's relatively easy to coerce "Unbalanced scopes/saves/tmps/context" errors from `threads` when doing so.

Comment: how do I timeout a command inside a thread without forking then ?
If alarm is preserved across exec, it should work, but if it isn't safe, maybe I need another solution. What could work ?